# Why can't I get my SharePoint custom workflow activity DLL to update?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I have created a custom activity that I am using in my workflows.  Initially changes that I made were picked up right away.  Now for some reason it keeps running with an old version of the DLL.  Is this cached somewhere?  I have tried the following:

- update-spsolution -identity
  copy_special.wsp -literalpath
  c:\temp\copy_special.wsp
  -GACDeployment (I think this reboots the app pool in IIS)
- Manually recycling the app pool in IIS
- canceling all instances of the workflow on sharepoint, uninstalling the workflow, updating the solution, then installing all over again
- Deleting cached files for SharePoint Developer on my local machine
- REBOOTING THE SERVER!

I have confirmed that the updated version of the DLL is in the GAC.  I'm about to loose it here.  Is there something else I should try?  Is there a location that this DLL might be cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was caused by user error.  When I rebuilt my project in VS 2010 I assumed it was updating the WSP.  It was not...  It only updated the DLLs.  I went ahead and redeployed it to my dev environment, THEN grabed the WSP and it finally updated.  PEBCAK!

Answer (score 2):

These are steps for the 2007 version of SharePoint Designer but maybe they are the same for 2010?

Try clearing the WebsiteCache on the computer that has SharePoint Designer installed:

> For Windows XP or Windows Server 2003:
>   Delete all directories and files at
>   %System Drive%\Documents and
>   Settings\%user%\Local
>   Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebSiteCache
>
> For Windows Vista or Windows Server
>   2008: Delete all directories and files
>   at %System
>   Drive%\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointworkflow/thread/34632798-6e45-4eb3-ad3d-2f941c706cda

Comment: Yeah, tried that already.  That was the `Deleting cached files for SharePoint Developer on my local machine` that I tried.

Comment: Ah sorry. What kind of changes did you make that aren't being picked up? Did you try an `IISRESET`?

Comment: I went into the IIS manager and recycled the app pool which I believe is the same as an IISRESET.  The most basic change is adding logging to the workflow history.  The current versions logs an exception when it occures.  I added an extremely basic logging of the word "test" to the workflow history but it did not take.  This change was added on the line above the exception log.

Comment: Also, rebooting the server should have covered the IISRESET possibility correct?

Comment: Yeah you definitely shouldn't need to reboot the whole server and I think that counts as a reset. :) IISRESET recycles all of the app pools instead of just one of them. Have you tried totally uninstalling the WSP and making sure the DLL is gone? The only other thing I can think of is that you are packaging up the wrong DLL (ex: debug vs release).